# Small signal analysis of pmos

Tags: transistors

[image]

How would i carry out the small signal analysis of the below circuit?

Comment: Good question would be to share how much you know already about small signal analysis follwed by asking where to start with for the circuit.

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace both MOSFETs by their hybrid-pi model for a 1st simple approach. Then complicate the analysis by upgrading the model with parasitic terms. Wikipedia has an article on the hybrid-pi models

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid-pi_model

and there is a complete lecture here

http://www.prenhall.com/howe3/microelectronics/pdf_folder/lectures/mwf/lecture12.fm5.pdf

Once you have a linear circuit, simplify, rearrange and apply node/mesh analysis. If needed, fast analytical circuit techniques or FACTs can help.

Good luck!

Comment: I will try to analyze using hybrid pi model